# IllegalArgumentException error on Android application: GCM key not found

Tags: android, firebase, push

The application builds fine, but when testing (either be it emulator or a phone), it crashes after installing, and the following error occurs:

```
IBM.MCE 3.6.3.0 : GcmDeliveryChannel: GCM app key or project number is not available
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
    Process: apptest.test, PID: 3759
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Init Process: Properties files doesn't contain GCM AppKey or GCM ProjectNum. If you don't want to support GCM add support.gcm=false to mce.properties
        at com.ibm.mce.sdk.gcm.GcmDeliveryChannel.initializeChannel(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.mce.sdk.registration.DeliveryChannelImpl.initialiseComponents(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.mce.sdk.registration.DeliveryChannel.initialiseComponents(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.mce.sdk.registration.RegistrationClientImpl.initSdk(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.mce.sdk.registration.RegistrationClientImpl.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.mce.sdk.registration.RegistrationClientImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run
```

I can provide snippets of my code and configuration files on request, but I won't upload it whole due to presentation reasons.

What the application does is basically being a push notification receiver from IBM Marketing Cloud, using IBM Push Notifications, which itself connects to GCM to send pushes to connected devices.

Any more explanations I am willing to give, accordingly, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an MceConfig.json file that lets you specify the Google project number and the app key you defined in the IBM Marketing Cloud. Look for

```
"senderId": "YOUR GCM PROJECT ID"
```

and

```
"appKey": {
  "prod":"YOUR APP KEY"
}
```

and replace them with the values you have. See the sample app for more details.

Comment: Sorry for the REALLY late accepted answer,  but to confirm to anyone having this problem, this does help out.